# dynamic contenct distributed evenly between 2 columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have website with various number of elements, which vary in size. I want to divide it  into 2 columns, with following rules:

1) first element goes to first column
2) element n goes to column that is shorter

how to achieve this?

Comment: What is the short mean is? by col height or element count?  and what is your try code or html file?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Masonry JS](http://masonry.desandro.com/). It can do what you want.